# Views listing of content types a user is allowed to create

Tags: views, users, nodes

My site allows any user to register but I can verify who they are and then assign a role if I am satisfied.

Can anyone tell me how I can list the content type(s) a user with a particular role is allowed to create? Is this accomplishable via Views?

I also need to detect if they are allowed to create content and display a message to them if they are not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like @googletorp said, you can't do this with Views, you will have to create a custom module.  If you are creating your own module, this short snippet will give you an array (`$types`) with the links to content types the logged in user can create (D6).  If the user cannot create any content types it will show a message:

```
<?php
  $types = array();
  foreach (node_get_types('types', NULL, TRUE) as $type) {
    if (node_access('create', $type->type)) {
      $types[$type->type] = l($type->name, 'node/add/' . str_replace('_', '-', $type->type));
    }
  }
  if (count($types) == 0) {
    drupal_set_message('You cannot create any content types!', 'warning');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really something you can do with views. If you go to node/add you get the list of content types you can create. You could look in the code and copy/paste it to create a list of content types a user can create or simply link to that page instead.

Comment: Thanks but my client is insisting on having a dropdown list of node types an authenticated user can create

Comment: @sisko Best way of doing that is to either explain to the client why it is a bad idea (decreased usability) or to create the form and get the options like explained in a custom module.